# Jumping to last position when reopening file: how to place line in center instead of bottom?

Tags: vimrc

Currently my vimrc has the following:

```
" Uncomment the following to have Vim jump to the last position when
" reopening a file
au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
```

This jumps to the last position when reopening a file, which is good. However, this position occasionally starts at the bottom of the screen. I often find myself using `zz` immediately after to center the line in the window. How can I make this centering always happen automatically?

---

Based on Maxim Kim's answer, I tried the following: `au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | exe "normal! zz" | endif`. This works *inconsistently*. Sometimes the last-visited line is placed in the center, whereas other times it is placed at the bottom. It seems to be essentially random - I can't reproduce the behavior consistently. Note that this works more often than `exe "normal! g'\"zz"` did.

Comment: what about adding `zz` to what you already have?

Comment: are you sure it is "random"? Have you tried to check if your `'"` mark line number is in buffer lines range for the file where it didn't work?

Comment: I would bet it isn't actually random, but I've been unable to find a way to cause it consistently thus far. Can you explain how I'd check what you're describing? I'm not familiar with that

Comment: well, looks like it depends on a filetype -- for some of them I can confirm I have the same issue as you have. I mean If I grab the contents of the file where it doesn't work and put it into plain text and do the same -- it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have all details needed to solve your issue -- `zz`.

Add it to the

```
exe "normal! g`\""
```

Where `exe` executes a string as ex commands (here it is needed to overcome vimscript limitations with | and autocommand). Normal commands could be executed as ex commands using `normal` ex command... anyway this line jumps to a mark `"` without changing jumplist (as stated in `:h g'`).

With

```
exe "normal! g`\"zz"
```

you should get what you need.

```
" restore cursor position
augroup restore_pos | au!
    au BufReadPost *
                \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &ft !~# 'commit'
                \ |   exe "normal! g`\"zz"
                \ | endif
augroup end
```

**UPDATE**

Looks like for `zz` another event should be used instead of `BufReadPost`:

```
" restore cursor position
augroup restore_pos | au!
    au BufWinEnter *
                \ if line("'\"") >= 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") && &ft !~# 'commit'
                \ |   exe 'normal! g`"zz'
                \ | endif
augroup end
```

Here `BufWinEnter` is used instead and by its description it is fired when buffer is *displayed* in a window. I guess *displayed* is a key here -- vim can't center position for the buffer which is not *yet displayed* and that might happen with `BufReadPost` event.

Comment: This is not working for me. Adding `zz` where you specified does not fix the behavior of it still opening with the last-visited line at the bottom of the screen. Also, worth noting, my line says `normal! g'\""` (g apostrophe), whereas yours says `normal! g\`\""` (g backtick). Not sure if relevant but I thought I'd point it out

Comment: Well, works in my vim

Comment: Please see my edit to the question adding new information. Does this lead to any insights?

Comment: try to figure out whether your `if` condition is true for the buffers where it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, the `BufWinEnter` line works consistently! Thanks for the help :)